# Передать extra в системный Intent для идентификации

Tags: android, android-intent

Хочу реализовать следующую функцию

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (type) {
        case cover:
        case logo:
        case photo:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            ((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, Decorator.PICK_IMAGE_GROM_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
    }
}
```

Функция вызывается из класса, не имеющего отношения к контексту.

id это идентификатор view элемента, который находится в динамически создаваемой программным способом разметке. Передавать его я хочу чтобы понимать в какой из плейсхолдеров мне загружать полученное из галереи изображение. Собственно в активити я ловлю результат, но Intent data не содержит поля с ключем id, то есть при возвращении из галереи изначальный Intent теряется. Есть ли способ передать данные в системный интент (например вызов галереи) для дальнейшей идентификации view, вызвавшего его, в onActivityResult?

Answer (score 3):

Специально для этого и придуман `requestCode`.
Он может быть любым целым значением и больше нуля, тогда вызываемый вернет то же значение вызывающему.
Вот и передавайте туда `id` вашего элемента разметки, он же уникальный?
Либо что-то другое, из чего можно извлечь `id`.